# Java - Confused about a particular inheritance scenario

Tags: java, inheritance

Say I have a class called A, and in A there's a method called `myMethod()`. Now say I make a subclass of A, called SubA, and in SubA I override `myMethod()` to make it do what I want it to. Now say I have another method in A called `myOtherMethod()` which calls `myMethod()` (from within the same class). I do not override `myOtherMethod()` in SubA. If I now call `myOtherMethod()` from inside SubA, it will clearly run A's `myOtherMethod()`. But does this now call the `myMethod()` as defined in A, or as defined (and overridden) in SubA?

To further confuse things, does it matter at all whether `myMethod()` were an interface method for some interface that class A implemented?

Comment: This seems pretty easy to try out and see what happens...

Comment: Why don't you try it by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to try - the fact  that A implements an interface or not does not make a difference:

```
public class A {

    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("A.myMethod()");
    }

    public void myOtherMethod() {
        System.out.println("A.myOtherMethod()");
        myMethod();
    }

    public static class SubA extends A {

        @Override
        public void myMethod() {
            System.out.println("SubA.myMethod()");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        SubA subA = new SubA();
        a.myMethod(); //A.myMethod()
        subA.myMethod(); //SubA.myMethod()
        a.myOtherMethod(); //A.myOtherMethod() + A.myMethod()
        subA.myOtherMethod(); //A.myOtherMethod() + SubA.myMethod()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create instance of `SubA` then calling method `myOtherMethod()` (which is in `A`) calls method `myMethod()` defined in `SubA` because it overrides method defined in `A`.